# is it possible to schedule automatic power on of server "hp dl360p gen8"?

Tags: hp-proliant

I do not use server at night so I want to turn it on at 9.00 a.m. and turn off at 11.00 p.m.

Turning off is trivial I can just schedule corresponding task in OS. On my old home computer I was using special option in BIOS which allows to schedule when computer should be turned on.

But I can't find such BIOS option on my server HP DL360p Gen8.

- Am I correct that it is not possible to schedule server turn on in BIOS?
- What options do I have?
- I do not want to use wake up on LAN because LAN might not be available by some reason (no Internet etc.)

Comment: What OS are you using? Under Windows you could schedule a task which could wake up your system.

Comment: Does this proliant come with a remove access card (e.g. HP ILO?) No experience here with HPs but Dell could be powered on via their DRAC (Dell remove access card) and those accept things like ssh. So worst case you could wake another computer at that time, have it ssh to the ILO and power up the proliant.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the automatic power-on state

```
From the System Utilities screen, select System Configuration > BIOS/Platform Configuration (RBSU) > Server Availability > Automatic Power-On and press Enter.
Select a setting and press Enter.
    Always Power On—The system automatically returns to a power on state.
    Always Power Off—The system automatically returns to a power off state.
    Restore Last Power State—The system automatically returns to its previous power off state.
Press F10.
```

Comment: This is the right answer, no OS-dependant features or extra electronics needed.

Answer (score 0):

In OS you can write a shell to turn off the server at a specific time! BUT you can't turn On the server From OS! Also BIOS!

If you want to turn off and on the server on specific time you have to think in Electric timer.

Best regards,

Comment: Electric timer is not possible as I co-locate server.

Comment: also some computers support wake on alarm in power management area of computer BIOS, unfortunately HP DL360p Gen8 doesn't have such option.

Comment: Yes Electric Timer is not possible in co-locate servers. I said every thing i know, Sorry at all.

Answer (score 0):

**If you use Linux** you can program it to wake up at a specified time. I'm not sure if it works for every Linux variant but you can try it out:

`/root/bin/shutwake.sh`

```
# unset alarm, set new time
sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm" 
sh -c "echo `date '+%s' -d '+ 600 minutes'` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm" 
/sbin/poweroff
```

Then you need to add a line in cron to shutdown:

```
0     23      *       *       *       /root/bin/shutwake.sh
```

I use this in a couple of rack servers and works like a charm.